# How to change @Input value of a component starting from a sibling

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a select component (combo box) generated n-times with the ngFor by the parent.

```
<myComponent *ngFor="let dropdown_element of dropdown_menu" [disable_flag]="dropdown_element.isDisabled"></myComponent>
```

setting the @Input disable_flag as 'false' I initialized as disabled two of three elements.

I wanna change the value in 'true' after the selection of an option of the enabled one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Output in the component MyComponent to tell the parent component which dropdown element should be enabled.

Hope the code below helps you to achieve that:

```js
// Parent component:

<myComponent *ngFor="let dropdown_element of dropdown_menu" [dropdownElement]="dropdown_element" (enableEl)="enableElement($event)"></myComponent>


export class ParentComponent {
    dropdown_menu = [ ... ];
    enableElement(element): void {
        dropdown_menu.forEach(el => {
            if (el.id === element.id) {
                el.isDisabled = false;
            } else {
                el.isDisabled = true;
            }
        });
    } 
}

// Child component:

import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myComponent',
    //...
})
export class MyComponent {

    @Output() enableEl = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input() dropdownElement;
 
    enable():void {
        this.enableEl.emit(dropdownElement);
    } 
}
```